# Implement project with maven in another maven project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have created a Java project with maven that I want to implement in other maven project.

The child project is not a spring project, is a Java project created from scratch migrated to maven to manage the dependencies.

I can generate the jar with `mvn install`. So far so good.

Then I try to implement this jar to other project that is built with maven and spring.

For that I added that jar to my local maven repo with the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/Users/.../target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=com.mycompany.childapp -DartifactId=childapp -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then I am able to see that in the repo folder in .m2, the jar file is correct.

And this in the parent project pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.childapp</groupId>
      <artifactId>childapp</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>
```

And also, in the plugin section:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

At least for eclipse everything is good, as I can develop and implement the classes inside the library without any issue. I can build the parent app with `mvn clean package` But when I run the app and try to execute the section of the code that uses the child library I get `ClassNotFoundException` for the classes that are in the child project.

In the parent project, in the libraries imported by maven I see that my library has a folder icon instead of the one the other have.

[image]

**How could this be fixed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was that the library was like... 'corrupted'.. or something like that.. It was a Java Project (created with eclipse wizard) than then I converted to maven (with eclipse wizard).

I started a new project as maven project from the beggining and everything was working at the first attempt....

So I just have to run `mvn clean install` to generate the jar and installed in the .m2 repo

Then in the main app pom.xml I have to declare as any other dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>mylibrary</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

`mvn clean package` creates jar for parent project but it does not include child jar.

You should use SpringBoot

- `mvn bootRun` to run your project locally
- `mvn bootJar` to build fat jar which will include all required dependencies.

  To run this fat jar call `java -jar parent.jar`

Comment: But I run the project locally using Run as server on eclipse. In that way I’m getting the ClassNotFoindException. Do I need to use SprintBoot to get the classes inside the library?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Eclipse. IJ IDEA puts all required dependencies on classpath when you run project from IDE and I believe Eclipse must do the same.

I advise you try two different ways above and if these work then problem with Eclipse and you can re-write your question to signify that.

Comment: But I'm having this issue when trying to run the parent project locally, so I'm not building that to be deployed in a server. So the child component is the one that seems to be missing their classes when I added to the main proyect

Comment: `mvn bootRun` runs project locally. It just do not use Eclipse to run it. If this command works then it is Eclipse who cannot parse correct project. If this command does not work then maven pom is incorrect. 

In other words, I'm jsut helping you to narrow problem

Answer (score -1):

As per the comments, you want to create a project with maven which will create a jar file. That jar file will be used in another project. If my understanding is correct. You have to do the followings.

1. Create a simple maven project with simple type archetype.
2. Run the pom.xml with the command like `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean package`.
3. Use the jar file from the simple project upload into your nexus/artifactory repository and use the maven definition in another maven project.

If you do not have nexus or artifactory, you can use the jar file locally in another maven project.

To add a jar file locally in another project, you have to add the following dependency structure in pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>your group id</groupId>
    <artifactId>name of the application</artifactId>
    <version>some version</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>your location/jar-file-name.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: thanks! Could you provide more info about how to use the jar locally? As In that case I'm getting ClassNotFoundException, do I need any specific config in the pom.xml or in other place?

Comment: @Sambit `<systemPath>your location/jar-file-name.jar</systemPath>` is road to nowhere. I cannot imagine any project/problem where it is best way to solve problem

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, it is an example, user has to set the path as his/her system.If you look into his question, he is creating a jar file from a project. For example, jar file name is a.jar and imagine, it is located in D:/myproject/a.jar, user can set the path accordingly in dependency as I have provided.

Comment: I understand that path should be changed to match local env. However, if you manage project with maven then there is no needs to use `systemPath`. You should rely on Maven's repo **because it is only way to make project to do not depend on particular host/PC**. Read this page https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies System dependencies are deprecated. Moreover, even before deprecation there were intended to be used with JDK libs not with user defined libs

Comment: I agree, but here user wants to do in a different way. Actually it should be a multi-module project.

Comment: It does not have to be multi-module. You can have separate project for library, develop it and install/deploy to local/remote Maven repo once ready. Then you can refer to this library like you do when it is 3rd party library.

Comment: Agreed, it is better to upload the jar file in Nexus or Artifactory so that other developers can use. Installing locally can be useful for the same developer who has done it locally but others cannot use. I have mentioned the usage of Nexus.

Comment: After adding the system path and scope I'm getting the same ClassNotFoundException...  About  a remote repo, that sounds great but as far as I see there are a bit expensive and there is not a free version (the library to add it's a very small project) so for now it's not the right option, for that reason, I want it to include that jar locally, but so far I wasted a full day trying to make it works

Comment: ClassNotFoundException is a runtime exception. First of all, if you do not set the jar file locally, you should get compilation issue. Are you getting compilation issue while building the application ?

Comment: No... I can build both, the child and the parent projects without any issue... but when I call a method that include a class of a child proyect, I get the ClassNotFoundException. For example, I have a class in the child call `Init`so when a part of the parent instantiate the Init class I get the exception

Comment: I mean, the build issues are gone when I install the library in the local maven repo and add the reference to the pom to the library

Comment: One more question... When I add the library without maven (just adding with the Properties -> Java Build Path option) and try to run the app I get a lot of errors as if  spring cannot instantiate all the @Autowired classes and this happens when the spring-config.xml file is not correctly updated. Could be that I need to explain in any way to Spring that I'm adding a jar file? Because as far as I can imagine, in this way there shouldn't be any error...

Comment: I wonder why do you use Maven and SpringBoot if all you want is to make it running from Eclipse?

Comment: Running from eclipse is not all I want to do... is just for the development phase... I use maven to manage the dependencies and to build the project. I'm not an expert in maven or spring, so for sure I can optimize some things.. but for now, I want to make this work... I'm still getting ClassNotFoundException but the jar is correctly installed in the local maven repo and reference in the project

Comment: "but for now, I want to make this work" - and I told you what to do.

Comment: I already try that but I get `NoClassDefFoundError: com/mycompany/childapp/business/Init`

Comment: can you paste full POMs of parent and child projects?